# How to avoid an application restart after crash on windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, application-restart

I'm having a MFC-Dialog based 64bit application written using Visual Studio 2015.

My problem is that the application is starting automaticity after a crash but only if it's running for longer. It seems to be somehow related to WER, but I didn't have any of the function calls implemented listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/recovery/registering-for-application-restart

Thank you in advance

Greg

Comment: The link you posted seems to answer all questions you seem to be having (it explains, that your application needs to be running for 60 seconds to be considered for restart, why that is, as well as what `RESTART_NO_CRASH` flag is for). It's not immediately clear, what problem you are having.

Comment: If you made your MFC project with the wizzard, and checked "restart manager", it will add `m_dwRestartManagerSupportFlags` in your `CMyWinApp` class. This ends up calling the restart manager.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I didn't know about the restart manager.